# how to create a string from string array or arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

how can i extract all the elements in a string [] or arraylist and combine all the words with proper formating(with a single space) between them and store in a array..

```
String[] a = {"Java", "is", "cool"};
```

Output: Java is cool.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
String[] strings = {"Java", "is", "cool"};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String string : strings) {
    if (builder.length() > 0) {
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append(string);
}

String string = builder.toString();
System.out.println(string); // Java is cool
```

Or use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`StringUtils#join()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Iterator,%20char%29).

```
String[] strings = {"Java", "is", "cool"};
String string = StringUtils.join(strings, ' ');
System.out.println(string); // Java is cool
```

Or use Java8's [`Arrays#stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-).

```
String[] strings = {"Java", "is", "cool"};
String string = Arrays.stream(strings).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(string); // Java is cool
```

Answer (score 7):

My recommendation would be to use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(a, " ");
```

Comment: Can you please explain how can I import this in a project in Netbeans.

Comment: Not reinventing the wheel. So I would also suggest this method.

Comment: The org.apache.commons link is dead.