# Convert array of Strings to String

Tags: java, string

Hello i have a little problem with array conversion

i want to convert this array format `["x","z","y"]` To this String Format `('x','y','z')` with commas and parentheses.

btw this array is dynamic in size may be increased or decreased

this is my try

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String [] arr = {"x","y","z"};
        String s = "(";

        for(int i = 0; i <arr.length;i++){
            s +="'".concat(arr[i]).concat("'") + ',' ;
            if(i == arr.length-1)
                s.replace(',', ')');
        }

        System.out.print(s);

    }
```

this is my output ('x','y','z', 
 i want to replace the last comma with ')'

Comment: dont expect that the members here will write your code. tell us what is the issue you are facing with the code..

Comment: code added check again

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925420/how-to-create-a-string-from-string-array-or-arraylist and an array has a fixed capacity, use an implementation of `List` if you wish to have dynamic capacity.

Comment: Use StringBuilder instead of String

Comment: my string must starts and ends with parentheses my problem with the parentheses in the end of the string.

Comment: ('x','y','z', this is my output i want to replace the last comma with ')'.

Comment: @MohamedNagy reading the documentation is often helpful [replace(char oldChar, char newChar) - Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also will do the magic..

Please use StringBuilder for these kind of string operations..

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            s += "'".concat(arr[i]).concat("'") + ',';
        }

        s = s.concat(")");

        System.out.print(s.replace(",)", ")"));
```

Comment: ('x','y','z',) i don't need the last comma

Comment: the last comma will get replaced

Answer (score 0):

`s.replace(',', ')');`

Here you are trying to replace the comma, but Strings in java are immutable, it means you are in fact replacing this, but not assigning the value to any variable, so it's pointless. Also, that replace will not do what you think. Instead, you need to:

`s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);`

This is gonna remove the last character from the String (that is extra comma at the end). Then just append `)` to it and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the String.join method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] arr = {"x","y","z"};        
    String s  = String.join("','", arr);
    s = "('"+s+"')";
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, using `String.format` and `String.join`

```
    String[] arr = { "x", "y", "z" };
    String s = String.format("('%s')", String.join("','", arr));
    System.out.println(s);
```

It print

```
('x','y','z')
```

**Edit**

If you are using jdk7, you can use `StringBuilder` to avoid performance issues, as shown in the code:

```
    String[] a = { "x", "y", "z" };
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b.append("'").append(String.valueOf(a[i])).append("'");
        b.append((i == a.length - 1) ? ")" : ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(b);
```

It print

```
('x','y','z')
```

Comment: i'm using jdk 7

Comment: so you can try the code with the `StringBuilder` to avoid performance issues if you concatenate using `String`